# Mock HttpContext.Current in HangFire

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hangfire

`HttpContext.Current` is null when fire job in Hang Fire!!
because i want to use `await UserManager.FindAsync();`
should inject `HttpContext.Current` to HangFire or not and How??

Answer (score 1):

You should not set `HttpContext.Current` when you are not handling an HTTP request.

Instead, extract all the information necessary and pass it explicitly to your background job.

Comment: but I have to use Identity Methods to add multiple users from Excel File so i have to use `UserManager.CreateAsync();` >> i can not use  these methods because `HttpContext.Current` is null !!!